# Simple Swing example - method ordering results in no output

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I'm a newbie to Swing. Yesterday I got stuck in this.

The code:-

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
JButton b = new JButton("CLICK");
b.setBounds(130,100,100,40);
f.add(b);
f.setSize(400,500);//1st
f.setLayout(null);//2nd
f.setVisible(true);//3rd
```

When I run the above code, it displays an output of a button named "CLICK" placed inside a frame. But, if I reorder the last 3 methods like this:

```
f.setVisible(true);
f.setLayout(null);
f.setSize(400,500);
```

Then, the frame is displayed with no button inside it. 
why ?

Comment: The way to fix problems with not using a layout manager is to ***use* a layout manager.**  As an aside.  `f.setLayout("null");` does not compile whereas `f.setLayout(null);` does.  Please do not post 'something like' the code being used.  Instead post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Sorry, its actually       f.setLayout(null);

Comment: Brother my question is that if i use the methods in the order 
setSize 1st, setLayout 2nd and setVisible 3rd than it do works. But if i use the methods in the order setVisible 1st, setLayout 2nd and setSize 3rd than frame is displayed but no button inside it. 
I'm asking why is this so by reordering ? 
Thank's

Comment: *"I'm asking why is this so by reordering ?"*  If I tell you why, you'll likely still be using `null` layouts (and still asking how to fix them).  If not you, then perhaps 10 more naive people that read this Q&A.  Until you post a more sensible code example that follows best practices, I'm not answering questions.

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix problems with not using a layout manager is to ***use*** a layout manager.

For example, this GUI uses layouts, margins and padding to achieve the same basic look as might be seen in the first GUI.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ButtonGui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Button GUI");
                JButton b = new JButton("CLICK");

                // adjust numbers to requirement
                b.setMargin(new Insets(12, 35, 12, 35));
                // since a button has a border, we need a panel to which
                // we can add a 2nd (empty) border.
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
                // adjust numbers to requirement
                p.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(100, 130, 100, 130));
                p.add(b);
                f.add(p);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

.setVisible(true) is always the last method call. you set the characteristics of your swing component, then use this method to tell it to display itself. HTH.

Comment: *"`.setVisible(true)` is always the last method call."*  Not *always*.  Components can be added dynamically after the GUI is visible.  The real problem that should be fixed is trying to use a `null` layout manager.

Answer (score -1):

I was to suffering from same problem.
try the code in the following manner..

```
f.setSize(800,800);
f.setLayout(null);
f.setVisible(true);
```

used in eclipse.works fine!!!

Comment: Please stop giving GUI advice at least until you realize why that is such a bad idea.